# Xcode 4: Files get stuck outside of project, unable to be deleted

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Lots of my files in my Xcode project get "stuck" outside of my project and I'm unable to delete them. This happens occasionally when creating new files (maybe 50% of the time).

Here's a screenshot of what happens:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same problem, solved editing manually the project bundle:

- quit xcode
- right click on "Philly Shows.xcodeproj" and show its content
- same operation on "project.xcworkspace"
- open "contents.xcworkspacedata" with a text editor: you'll find references to your stuck groups and files, remove what you want to remove, basically your file should be something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Workspace version = "1.0">
        <FileRef
            location = "self:Philly Shows.xcodeproj">
        </FileRef>
    </Workspace>
```

Michele

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it saved me from having to just create a new project.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks!  I've been having this insurmountable problem for months!